# Magento 2 Testing Attributes

Tags: magento2, attributes, best-practice, testing, integration-test

I've just started working on Magento 2. I created my first custom attribute for the customer entity and now i would like to create a test for it. As far as i understand it, this should be an integration test and not a unit test.

But anyway what i want do to is test if the attribute is actually created for the entity. Could someone please explain to me if this is even a good practise, if so can someone hook me up with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so after reading the documentation of magento i decided to use the integration framwork that comes with the installation.

You can read the article [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/test/integration/integration_test_execution.html).

What i came up with was the following:

```
<?php

use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap;

class SetupTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $attributeRepository;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->attributeRepository = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->get(AttributeRepositoryInterface::class);
    }

    public function testIfAttributeDebtorIdExists()
    {
        $attribute = $this->attributeRepository->get('customer', 'my_custom_attribute');
        $this->assertEquals('my_custom_attribute', $attribute->getAttributeCode());
    }
}
```

This works fine, i'm going to expand it with a failing test and an exception test.